# Is there any way to adjust the width of taskbar items on Gnome desktop?

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel, taskbar

Is there any way in which the width of items on the taskbar (or, rather, the lower panel) of the Gnome (2.32.0) desktop (Ubuntu 10.10) can be adjusted to take a more sensible width?

While I *can* see the icons of the applications they represent, they seem a little over-compressed, given the width of the desktop/monitor resolution (1900 x 1080):

[image]

[Click the image, or this link, for a full-sized (1920x169, 169.7KB) graphic](http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/linked/screenGrab.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not normal behaviour for the task bar. If you are using the standard task bar, you have something blocking it. Right click your panel and click on "Add To Panel", then drag the applet/separator that is blocking the taskbar.

Comment: That's odd, there was (on a zoom of around 3200%) a 2x2px item that was preventing the panel's full use. The odd part is *I don't recall ever adding anything to **that** panel.* +1, and accepted.